# PHP exec() on windows not working

Tags: php, exec

Hey, I'm trying to execute a program on windows through PHP, the command is posted below.  This doesn't seem to be running through the script at all, even though it works when the command is manually entered into the command prompt.

```
exec('C:\\ffmpeg -i ' . $movedfile . ' -acodec aac -ab 128k -vcodec libx264 -fpre C:\\ffmpeg\\share\\ffmpeg\\libx264-hq.ffpreset -crf 22 -threads 0 -wpredp 0' . $convertedfile);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: if you put the thing your execing into a variable and echo $var;
exec($var); does the echod var definitely work?

Answer (score 12):

1. You are missing a space at the end
2. You should really use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Comment: THANK YOU, that space is what was causing the problem.  God, sometimes you just need another set of eyes to look over your code.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

```
exec('C:\ffmpeg -i  ....
```

this would mean you would have `ffmpeg.exe` in your C:\ root directory. I think you mean

```
exec('C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg -i  ....
```

Comment: no, it's located in my C root directory for testing purposes. I've also tried what plod suggested

Comment: $execvar = exec('C:\\ffmpeg -i ' . $movedfile . ' -acodec aac -ab 128k -vcodec libx264 -fpre C:\\ffmpeg\\share\\ffmpeg\\libx264-hq.ffpreset -crf 22 -threads 0 -wpredp 0' . $convertedfile);

debug ($execvar);

but there is no value within execvar

Answer (score 0):

try running only the command itself without any options and see if that help. moreover try to run something simple first - `dir` etc.

Comment: when I exec dir, it does return results:

8 Dir(s)  549,287,497,728 bytes free

Comment: so exec works. there is some problem with the way you have your ffmpeg + options written.

Comment: Some processes need elevation and to be run from within the context of a GUI user, not the System, please check the solutions here for a possible answer in case some calls to `system` work and others don't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769800/apache-service-php-exec-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Did you check permissions?  Assuming standard configurations, IUSR_MACHINENAME needs read + execute permissions to the executable, any source/output files, and any temporary directories/files

Comment: Yes... IUSR_MACHINENAME is a standard Windows system user that IIS uses to execute/access website files by default.