# Php exec command not working on Windows, works on command line

Tags: php, command-line

I am trying to execute the following command via PHP's `exec` function:

```
D:\\pstill -F a4 -2 -c -c -c -c -g -i -t -K -d 700 -a 4 -m XimgAsCMYK -m Xspot -m Xoverprint -o D:\\outputfile.pdf D:\\new.jpg
```

It doesn't generate any output. But if I directly paste the command on the command line then it works...

Note: it takes a bit of time to complete when run directly on command line.

Comment: Do you receive any error message? Could you please tell us your code (not only the command you are executing)?

Comment: `exec("pstill -F a4 -2 -c -c -c -c -g -i -t -K -d 700 -a 4 -m XimgAsCMYK -m Xspot -m Xoverprint -o D:\\outputfile.pdf D:\\input.jpg");`

Comment: Make sure that your webserver's userid has the appropriate permissions to execute pstill, and read/write permissions on the D:\ root directory/drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your command is this:

```
exec("pstill -F a4 -2 -c -c -c -c -g -i -t -K -d 700 -a 4 -m XimgAsCMYK -m Xspot -m Xoverprint -o D:\\outputfile.pdf D:\\input.jpg");
```

PHP escapes the backslashes, so the command that reaches the shell is `... D:\outputfile.pdf D:\input.jpg`. You have to double-escape the backslashes: once for PHP and once for the shell.

```
exec("pstill -F a4 -2 -c -c -c -c -g -i -t -K -d 700 -a 4 -m XimgAsCMYK -m Xspot -m Xoverprint -o D:\\\\outputfile.pdf D:\\\\input.jpg");
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead of exec function here. shell_exec executes command via appropriate shell (WIndows / Unix etc) and returns the complete output as a string to you.

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was to

**run apache in a terminal window instead of a service.**

see this thread:
[apache service php exec not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769800/apache-service-php-exec-not-working)