# windows - php exec(), system(), passthru() not working (possible permissions issue)

Tags: php, windows

I am having trouble running commands via PHP, certain commands like `whoami` and `dir` work without problem.

When I try `system('notepad.exe');` the browser just hangs then I get max execution time error in my logs. This makes me think it is a permission error.

I tried running Acrobat Reader and FoxitReader using `system()` the browser hangs but I could see them in the tasklist, seem they are launching but they just hang and don't open up.

Windows 10 running PHP 5.5.30. Apache service is set as Log On As:Local System and I have tried changing Log On As to the account I login with and that didn't work.

Any help would be great.

*** EDIT ***

I want to run Acrobat / Word/ Excel to print their files via browser. The commands I want to use work in the command prompt but not in PHP that is why I think it is a permission issue. I used notepad as an example it will probably be related as its a simple command and should not have problems running it via `system()`.

*** SOLUTION ***

The problem was running Apache as a service you cannot launch GUI applications. See blow for solution to the problem.

[apache service php exec not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769800/apache-service-php-exec-not-working)
Answer by blackflims

Comment: What if you just run the PHP script (separate from Apache)?  What happens?  My follow-up question is why are you using Apache to launch an application like notepad?

Comment: @Devon I have tried `php -r "echo exec('notepad.exe');` from the command line and it works fine. I want to run Acrobat / Word/ Excel to print their files via browser. The command I want to use works in the command prompt without problems. I used notepad as it will be related as its a simple command and should not have problems running it via `system()`

Comment: If you can launch it with `php -r` then it is most likely an issue with the user that php is running under with Apache.

Comment: @Devon I guessed that buddy but do not have a clue on how to correct.

Comment: I don't know much about Windows but if you're running mod_php, then for linux it would be the value of httpd.conf's `User` directive.

Comment: In the case of `system('notepad.exe')` a hang is the expected behaviour; notepad.exe is starting up (in Apache's non-interactive session) and of course it just keeps running, waiting for someone to use it.  Same with Acrobat etc. unless you've specified a command line that causes it to automatically perform a task and then exit.

Comment: It should also be noted that printing from non-interactive sessions seems to be unreliable.  (And is as far as I know unsupported.)

Comment: Re your latest edit: note that you *can* launch GUI applications.  They just won't be visible.